# Deserialization of File type from Angular to Java using Jackson

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

In my REST application developed using SpringBoot and Angular, I need to send a REST request to SpringBoot back end in order to save a object into the database.

In the front end, user fills up a form and submits. Following is the interface from which a object is created in order to be sent to the backend as a REST call.

```
export interface TenderToPost{

    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    images: File[];
    referenceNumber: string;

}
```

The backend should deserialize the above object to a object of Following class in Java.

```
public class TenderDTO implements Serializable{

    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private List<MultipartFile> images;

    private String referenceNumber;

    // default constructor

    // geters and setters

}
```

As shown above, I need to accept the File sent from frontend as a `MultipartFile`.

However, when the request is sent from the front end, Jackson gives me the error

> Can not construct instance of
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile: abstract types either
>   need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or
>   contain additional type information

I am aware that that this error comes since I have used `MultipartFile` interface as the type of my images list.

What I thought of as the solution for this, is letting Jackson know to what type the list should be deserialized into using an annotation. So, I used following

```
@JsonDeserialize(contentAs = CommonsMultipartFile.class)
private List<MultipartFile> images;
```

CommonsMultipartFile is an implementation of `MultipartFile`. That is why I used it.

Now I get the following error.

> Can not construct instance of
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile: no
>   suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value
>   (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable
>   type information?)

Do I need to change the setter for the images list? Or is my whole approach incorrect?

Kindly show me the way how I should correct this.

Comment: did u find the solution for this?

Comment: @PankajSaboo I used a slightly different approach. I removed the file from DTO and now i send the file together with the DTO in a map.In the back end, i accept the back end as a map.(not directly as the dto i have mentioned in the question)

Comment: I did this change, way back :P

Comment: u consider 10 days as a long time eh

Comment: if you solved this problem (even with refactoring), it would be helpful to post a solution as an answer, currently people running into this sort of thing might not be able to figure this out without guidance. Just saying

Comment: Could you please post your solution to this problem? I ran into exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@JsonPropertyDescription` to construct object.
[@JsonPropertyDescription example](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations#jsonpojobuilder)